docker-compose escaping single quotes not working
docker-compose entrypoint tag escaping single quotes not working..
I tried the code to escape single quotes in docker-docker entrypoint tag. This works from my command line but doesn't work from docker-compose entrypoint...
Here is my sample code from test.yml:
version: "2.4"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: test
    image: "java-build:21-focal"
    entrypoint:
      /bin/bash -c "
      echo $'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal_visibility; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'temporal_admin\'@\'%\'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'temporal_admin\'@\'%\'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' > /tmp/init.sql;
      cat /tmp/init.sql
      "

Output:
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal_visibility; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO temporal_admin@%; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO temporal_admin@%; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

as you can see escaping single quotes doesn't work...any ideas?

This should fix it and retain single quotes:
version: "2.4"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: test
    image: "ubuntu:focal"
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo $'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal_visibility; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'temporal_admin\'@\'%\'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'temporal_admin\'@\'%\'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' > /tmp/init.sql;
        cat /tmp/init.sql

Output:
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS temporal_visibility; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'temporal_admin'@'%'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'temporal_admin'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Changes I did:

using a YAML array instead of string for entrypoint, this helps with consistency in shell argument processing
using YAML chomp | for multiline string

